# Websocket getting disconnected when app in background

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, websocket

I am facing an issue that slow down my app when a user open it from the background. Looking at the logs, it seems like the websocket is getting disconnected, then connected again which triggers my real time database functions, which update my redux store, which re-render my views. And that's what slows down my app.

I thought about handling my reconnection and disconnection with the following function from react-native but i don't think this is the right way to do it.

```
AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
```

Here are the logs i'm getting when i open the app from background after 5-10min:

```
c:0:0:0 Websocket connection was disconnected. 
util.js:133 c:0:0:0 WebSocket is closing itself 
util.js:133 c:0:0: Realtime connection lost. 
util.js:133 c:0:0: Closing realtime connection. 
util.js:133 c:0:0: Shutting down all connections 
util.js:133 p:0: data client disconnected 
util.js:133 p:0: Trying to reconnect in 0ms 
util.js:133 0: onDisconnectEvents 
app.js:150 distanceMi
app.js:151 0
util.js:133 p:0: Making a connection attempt 
util.js:133 getToken() completed. Creating connection. 
util.js:133 c:0:1: Connection created 
RCTLog.js:47 SocketRocket: In debug mode.  Allowing connection to any root cert
util.js:133 c:0:1:0 Websocket connecting to wss://s-usc1c-nss-249.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ls==&ns=instabo-production 
RCTLog.js:47 SocketRocket: In debug mode.  Allowing connection to any root cert
c:0:1:0 Websocket connected. 
util.js:133 c:0:1: Realtime connection established. 
util.js:133 p:0: connection ready 
util.js:133 p:0: {"r":10,"a":"auth","b":{"cred":"token"}} 
util.js:133 p:0: Listen on /instavice/variables for default 
util.js:133 p:0: {"r":11,"a":"q","b":{"p":"/instavice/variables","h":"gETk+lRA+OQ6CA3WxV1tJp899vk="}} 
util.js:133 p:0: Listen on /nurses/IEvkY2X161bf1IMgOMayW2oDq0l2 for default 
util.js:133 p:0: {"r":12,"a":"q","b":{"p":"/nurses/nurseID","h":"DZANoj/kEuhff2s4ng1Zie1q/24="}} 
util.js:133 p:0: Listen on /offersNurse for default 
util.js:133 p:0: {"r":13,"a":"q","b":{"p":"/offersNurse","h":"="}} 
util.js:133 p:0: from server: {"r":10,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{"auth":{"email_verified":true,"provider":"password","email":"birolleauf@wlnss.co","user_id":"","token":{"email_verified":true,"email":"birolleauf@wlnss.co","exp":1566869220,"user_id":"","iat":1566865620,"sub":"IEvkY2X161bf1IMgOMayW2oDq0l2","aud":"instabo-production","auth_time":1566865620,"iss":"https://securetoken.google.com/instabo-production","firebase":{"identities":{"email":["@wlnss.co"]},"sign_in_provider":"password"}},"uid":""},"expires":1566869220}}} 
util.js:133 c:0:1: Primary connection is healthy. 
util.js:133 p:0: from server: {"r":11,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{}}} 
util.js:133 p:0: listen response {"s":"ok","d":{}} 
util.js:133 p:0: from server: {"r":12,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{}}} 
util.js:133 p:0: listen response {"s":"ok","d":{}} 
util.js:133 p:0: from server: {"r":13,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{}}} 
util.js:133 p:0: listen response {"s":"ok","d":{}}
```

Here is the code i am using to get user data & offers in real time:

```
const OffersRef = getDatabase().ref('offersNurse')
      OffersRef.on('value', snap => {
          ///// some code
          /// update redux store
      }) 

const userRef = getDatabase().ref('nurses/' + userID)
                onValueUser = userRef.on('value', function(snap) {
                    ///// some code
                    /// update redux store
                })
```

I would like to implement a function that either keeps my websocket connected while the app in background, or a function that avoid my realtime function to get triggered again.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi Florian. How did you fix this issue? I'm having the same problem